# Chai, testing that function throws correct error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js

Basically, I am practicing testing with Mocha and I wrote a schema where a serial number is supposed to be unique. I want a test that shows that when I try to use that serial number again, it throws the Mongo Error E11000 for duplicate keys.

```
phaseSchema.statics.createPhase = function(name,sernum,desc){
  var phase = mongoose.model('phases', phaseSchema)
  var newphase = new phase({NAME: name, SERNUM: sernum,DESC: desc});
  newphase.save(function(err,newphase){
      if(err)
        return console.error(err);
  })
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways but I get timeout errors or have the assertion be ignored and I can't figure it out.

I feel like the closest I've gotten is

```
it("throws error when non unique sequence number is used", function(done){    
    (function () {
        ucdphase.createPhase('d0','develop',0,"desc")
    }).should.throw("E11000 duplicate key error index: test.ucdphase.$");

    done();
  });
```

but what happens then is it prints the error to the console and then says

```
"AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [chai documentation](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/), you should use `expect` to start assertion.

Also I don't think you need to use `done` callback. That callback is used to test asynchronous code.

Try this:

```
it("throws error when non unique sequence number is used", function(){    
    expect(function () {
        ucdphase.createPhase('d0','develop',0,"desc")
    }).to.throw("E11000 duplicate key error index: test.ucdphase.$");
  });
```

Comment: I tried that before and again now and it gives me  AssertionError: expected{ Object (__flags) } to be a function

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, Example now fixed: `should` replaced with `to`.

Comment: @Angie I still get the same error. How did it get solved for you?